# Configurar o caminho de saída do compilador no NetBeans

Tags: c, netbeans, compilação

Alguém saberia configurar no Netbeans, para que quando eu compilar um projeto, gere o executável em uma pasta determinada? Nas propriedades do projeto, tem a opção vinculador, que acredito que seja a saída do programa, lá esta este diretório:

```
${CND_DISTDIR}/${CND_CONF}/${CND_PLATFORM}/meu_prog
```

Alguém sabe o que significa essas macros? Como mudar este diretório?

Comment: Quando geramos o `.jar`da aplicação ele já vai para a pasta do projeto isso não te atende?

Comment: Não. Aqui o projeto esta em C.  O arquivo que ele gera é um .exe (Windows), mas no contexto, da na mesma do .jar que é o executavel de um projeto Java. Mas o que eu pretendo fazer, é que esse .exe ou .jar vá para um diretório definido, por exemplo, quero que após a compilação do projeto que esta na Pasta C:\Netbeans\ProjetoTest, o executável pare no meu Desktop, ou seja, o .exe ou .jar.

Comment: Seria apropriado mudar o título para algo parecido com "Configurar o caminho de saída do compilador no NetBeans" (é uma sugestão, como exemplo). Do jeito que está, parece que quer configurar o local que fica o gcc, javac ou outro compilador que esteja utilizando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é neste local que muda o destino do arquivo, só que o separador de diretórios é `/` e não `\`.

Se houver um diretório com o mesmo nome do arquivo de saída, pode precisar outros ajustes como colocar o .exe no final do nome na configuração de execução (`Propriedades -> Executar -> Comando Executar`).

A documentação do que significa está no arquivo `Makefile`, ou pelo menos pistas para as que não estão exatamente iguais às listadas. No projeto, fica numa pasta chamada **"Arquivos Importantes"** ou **"Important Files"** na versão em inglês.

- **CND_DISTDIR**: diretório de distribuição, onde os arquivos finais estarão;
- **CND_CONF**: Não diz, mas é a configuração usada, parece equivalente a `${CONF}`: Tem valor `Debug`, `Release` ou outro nome que você crie nas propriedades de projeto;
- **CND_PLATFORM**: a plataforma alvo, pelo que vi é o nome do compilador (definido por você) e o sistema operacional host que está construindo o programa. Pode ser `Cygwin_4.x-Windows`, ou `Arduino-Windows`, `Arduino-Linux`, `AVR-Linux`, etc.

Você também pode, sem alterar o destino do programa, copiar o mesmo para o local que quiser, adicionando o comando na seção `.build-post` do `Makefile`. Se quiser executar/debugar no novo local mudar as configurações dos comandos Executar e Depurar. Exemplo: depois das linhas

```
.build-post: .build-impl
# Add your post 'build' code here...
```

No Windows, adicione a linha:

```
${CP} ${CND_ARTIFACT_PATH_${CONF}}.exe ${USERPROFILE}/Desktop/
```

No Linux, a linha é:

```
${CP} ${CND_ARTIFACT_PATH_${CONF}} ${HOME}/Desktop/
```

**Importante**: Esta linha começa com um caractere `[Tab]`, do contrário não funciona.

**Importante 2**: Nem sempre o `${USERPROFILE}/Desktop/` funciona. Por exemplo: No Windows eu mudei a pasta do meu desktop, e este caminho não copia o arquivo para o meu desktop. (Porque mudei é outra história) No Linux o ambiente que uso nem usa a pasta Desktop.

Comment: Recebi este erro adicionando a linha que você passou: nbproject/Makefile-variables.mk:13: *** Variável recursiva `CND_ARTIFACT_PATH_Debug' faz referência a ela mesma (eventualmente).  Pare.
gmake: ** [.clean-impl] Erro 2

Comment: @Vynstus Nossa, aqui criei um projeto `appteste`, com `Makefile`, arquivo principal em `C`, ferramentas `Cygwin_4.x`. Fui no `Makefile`, colei a linha sem mexer, coloquei o caractere `TAB` (foi difícil, o NB insiste em transformar em espaços) e mandei rodar. Compilou e executou sem erros (pois nem tem código, só retorna). Ah, o arquivo foi para a pasta correta, que não é meu desktop. Quais as versões que usa? Meu NetBeans é 8.0.2, suporte a C/C++ 1.27.2.1, Cygwin 4.x com GCC 4.9.2. - No arquivo Makefile que o seu NB gera, tem a descrição da variável `CND_ARTIFACT_PATH_${CONF}` no início?

Comment: É a mesma versão, com suporte C/C++. Meu gcc é do Linux, o projeto do netbeans está usando o host de build de um servidor Linux, e o projeto é compilado lá. Diretorio onde ele grava o executavel é : /home/usuario/.netbeans/remote/192.168.1.x/pc-Windows-x86/C/Users/fulano/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Projeto_Teste/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86

Comment: Fiz no Linux: criei appteste, tudo igual, só que a linha é um pouco diferente, vou atualizar a resposta. De qualquer modo, a saída que você citou é outro problema. Verifique se o arquivo `{diretorio do projeto}/nbproject/Makefile-variables.mk` está sendo criado adequadamente. Se eu usar um de minhas unidades NTFS tenho problemas porque monto de maneira que impede execução, verifique isto também, tente criar um projeto local para testar. Neste arquivo, citado em seu primeiro comentário, a linha correspondente, no Linux, fica: `CND_ARTIFACT_PATH_Debug=dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/appteste`.

Comment: @Vynstus Ah, outra diferença, não que mude algo, mas no meu Linux a versão do GCC é gcc (Gentoo 4.8.4 p1.6, pie-0.6.1) 4.8.4

Comment: @Vynstus Ah, outra coisa: Se o host de build é um servidor Linux, pode ser que o Makefile seja interpretado no Linux e não possa copiar o arquivo diretamente para seu desktop, não sei exatamente como é feito e não consigo testar isto. Supondo que isto é verdadeiro e que todo o resto funcione, talvez você possa montar o disco no Linux e copiar para o local adequado.

Comment: Na verdade eu não queria copiar para o desktop do Windows e sim na pasta home do linux., meu gcc é esse: (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)

Comment: Bem, de qualquer maneira nunca usei host remoto para build no Netbeans. O mais próximo que cheguei disso foi compilação distribuída, sem NetBenas, mas aí o host central controla tudo e recebe os resultados, não os outros. Build em host remoto é uma complicação a mais e no momento não consigo testar tal ambiente.

Answer (score 0):

**@Rafael**

Estava precisando da mesma coisa, então encontrei uma resposta na comunidade inglês que me serviu.

Basicamente você pode trocar o diretório da pasta `dist` que se encontra seu `.jar` (ou `.exe`) alterando o valor da propriedade `dist.dir` no arquivo `project.properties` *(no caso de um projeto em java)* do seu projeto localizado na pasta `nbproject`

```
dist.dir = dist
```

Para:

```
dist.dir = /../Desktop
```

No meu caso coloquei o caminho da minha area de trabalho. Coloque o caminho completo ali da sua.

Link da resposta em inglês: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6416772)

Comment: Na minha pasta nbproject não tem o arquivo project.properties, nenhum arquivo com essa extensão. Só arquivos com extensão .bash, .xml e .mk. O meu projeto é uma aplicação C ai não sei se diferencia os arquivos...

Comment: Então, criei um projeto c aqui pra testar e aparentemente o equivalente no projeto `C` é o `laucher.properties` dentro da pasta `private` do `nbproject`. Testa nesse arquivo.

Comment: Achei, mas ele não tem a linha dist.dir = dist

Comment: Sim, mas creio que tem uma macro lá relacionada ao caminho dist que diz que você pode utilizar. Tenta alterá-la. E se você adicionar essa linha dist.dir=  ele da erro?

Comment: Não encontrei, elas todas estão marcadas como comentario, ou seja, com o prefixo #. Tentei adicionar a linha dist.dir= /../Desktop e compilou, mas o arquivo não foi para o desktop...

Comment: Vou tentar aqui e já lhe dou uma resposta.